# Prove that $ \det \left( A^{-1} \right) = \frac{1}{\det(A)} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

If I have a non-singular matrix $\bf A$, how can I prove the following?

$$ \det \left( {\bf A}^{-1} \right) = \frac{1}{\det({\bf A})} $$

I know that ${\bf A} {\bf A}^{-1} = {\bf I}$, but I am not sure what to do with that knowledge.

Comment: Do you know that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure what that help me with. Having a hard time putting 2 and 2 together.

Comment: What if you let $B = A^{-1}$?

Comment: why can I do that exactly?

Comment: The equation about determinants holds for *all* $A$ and $B$, so it holds if $B$ is something particular.

Comment: Since $\det(AB)=\det A\det B$, letting $B=A^{-1}$ gives $\det I=1=\det A\det(A^{-1})$, so $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det A}$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121697/determinant-of-the-inverse-matrix

Answer (score 34, accepted):

first of all we know that

$$\det(A \cdot  B)=\det(A)\times\det(B)$$

also we know that

$$A\times A^{-1}=I$$

we know that

$$\det(A \cdot A^{-1})=\det(I)$$

or

$$\det(A)\times\det(A^{-1})=\det(I)$$

Can you continue from this? Ask yourself: what is $\det(I)$?) Take the example of the $3\times 3$ identity matrix:

$$ I =  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \det(I) = 1$$

So,

$$\det(A)\times\det(A^{-1})=1$$

or

$$\boxed{\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}}$$

Comment: I assume the determinant of an identity matrix is 1, right? If so, then I understand this. Sorry, I just began learning Linear Algebra.

Comment: of course for  nXn  identity matrix has determinant one

Comment: @CuriousFellow for diagonal matrices, the determinant is simply the product along the diagonal