# Determinant of the inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse

I'm seeking for a proof of the following:

> Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. Then the determinant of $A^{-1}$ equals:
>   $$\left|A^{-1}\right|=|A|^{-1} $$

I don't know where to begin the proof.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, for all $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$?

Comment: The [determinant is multiplicative](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product).

Comment: @Casteels Yep , I do...

Comment: @Casteels Ok, that was TOO easy.. Thank you! Would you mind writing as an answer, to close the topic?

Comment: You do know that you can answer your own questions? It is perfectly aceptable after you've reached an answer by yourself to write down that answer, post it and accept it. Of course, if you want someone else to get the credit then letting them write an answer so they can get upvotes and and an accept isn't wrong either.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661633/prove-that-the-determinant-of-a-1-frac1deta-linear-algebra

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hint:* You know that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ *for all* $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$. So make a judicious choice for $B$...

Answer (score 5):

Exploiting the commutativity of the determinant operation with multiplication is probably the easiest way. That said, here is another approach.

The determinant of a square matrix is equal to the product of its eigenvalues.

Now note that for an invertible matrix $\mathbf A$, $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf A$ is and only if $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf A^{-1}$. To see this, let $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ be an eigenvalue of $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf x$ a corresponding eigenvector. Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf A\mathbf x=&\,\lambda\mathbf x\\
\Longrightarrow\qquad{\phantom{\lambda^{-1}}}\mathbf x=&\,\lambda\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf x\\
\Longrightarrow\qquad\mathbf \lambda^{-1}\mathbf x=&\,\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf x.
\end{align*}
That is, $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf A^{-1}$ corresponding to the same eigenvector $\mathbf x$. The other direction is analogous.

Hence, the determinant of $\mathbf A^{-1}$ is equal to the product of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A^{-1}$, which is the product of the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$, which is just the reciprocal of the determinant of $\mathbf A$.

Comment: But this method only proved the geometric multiplicity is same, but we need algebraic
multiplicity same right?

Comment: @wz0919 “The determinant of a square matrix is equal to the product of its eigenvalues.” For this statement to be literally true, one needs to “split” each eigenvalue with an algebraic multiplicity $>$$1$ into repeated distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm still confused: If $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, first we use $\lambda_1$ to get $\lambda_1^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$, that's right, but if we use $\lambda_2$ further,  we've already have  $\lambda_2^{-1} = \lambda_1^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ and nothing new is proved. I can't  understand why '$\lambda_1^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$' is different from  '$\lambda_2^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$'..

Comment: @wz0919 In this case, both $\lambda_1^{-1}$ and $\lambda_2^{-1}$ are repeated eigenvalues of $\mathbf A^{-1}$.

Comment: I think it's clearer using characteristic polynomial. We have: for any eigenvalue $ \lambda $ of $ A $, $ \lambda^{-1} $ is an eigenvalue of $ A^{-1} $. This is equivalent to: for any root $ \lambda $ of $ p_A(\nu) $(characteristic polynomial of $ A $), $ \lambda^{-1} $ is a root of $ p_{A^T}(\nu) $(characteristic polynomial of $ A^T $).
We need to prove $ 1/p_{A^T}(0) = p_A(0)$, so besides the match of roots, we still need the multiplicity of roots being same.

Answer (score 2):

By interpreting the determinant as the (signed) ratio between the hypervolume of $f_A(\Gamma)$ and the hypervolume of $\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a symplex associated with the canonical base and $f_A$ is the linear map associated with $A$, the claim is trivial, since:
$$ \left(f_A\right)^{-1} = f_{A^{-1}}. $$
This is just the classic "measure-theoretic" proof of Binet's theorem.